# What is the right approach to save device/app/browser name during login?

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, authentication, server

As you know Facebook saves login sessions and we can see them in settings where we've logged in.

Now, they show **IP address**, **Phone name** (if logged in with phone) and **App name** in the phone and **Browser name** in case we use browser.

Now, I want to store these info for my site using PHP and JavaScript. One way is to use PHP `$_SERVER` and use appropriate key like **REMOTE_ADDR**, **HTTP_USER_AGENT** etc. to save this info to my DB when user logs in successfully.

But there's a problem in it. **HTTP_USER_AGENT** gives a string and I find it hard to extract the browser name, OS name and device name. Further, it doesn't show me app name in case logged in to my service with app.

So is there any better and recommended way to do it? Wouldn't it be better if I handle this client side? The client that makes request to server it self sends Device name, OS name and other info.

2nd option seems to me better but I'm not sure if it is recommended.

Comment: Try this https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect